# Update all users in the Administrator Role

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to be able to update all users who have the Administrator checkbox selected without manually going through each of the user. In the same script I would like to add them to another Role. This way there is only one user with the Administrator checked.

I would like to use Sitecore PowerShell extensions module.

Comment: Updating answer to do help with roles now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In SPE you should be able to do the following to get a list of all users with the admin role.

1. This should get you users, with admin role who are not the default admin

```powershell
    $users = Get-User -Filter* 
    | Where-Object {$_.IsAdministrator -and $_.Profile.UserName -ne 'sitecore\admin'}
```

2. Then you should pipe through the `$users` variable add a new role and user set-user to remove admin writes by setting it to false

```powershell
    $users | ForEachObject { 
                Add-RoleMember -Identity developer -Members $_.Profile.UserName 
                Set-User -Identity $_Profile.UserName -IsAdministrator $false }
```

3. Complete script

```powershell
    $users = Get-User -Filter* | Where-Object {$_.IsAdministrator -and $_.Profile.UserName -ne 'sitecore\admin'}

    $users | ForEachObject {Add-RoleMember -Identity developer -Members $_.Profile.UserName Set-User -Identity $_Profile.UserName -IsAdministrator $false }
```

Worth referring to SPE gitbook for [User and Roles Commands](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security/users-and-roles) and [Set-User](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/set-user) documentation for more info on what you can change with Set-User and how you can get different users.

Comment: Would this get all the users who are checked as Administrator?

Comment: @ASURA updated answer this should, work as expected now